# Search in the bootstrap-select component is not working where data-token contains all numbers like "4730"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am using https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ for generating search options for the form selection. Search options are working for any strings accept strings that have numbers in them like **"4730"**.

I am populating data within select tag from a JSON. Here is my select tag -

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <select class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" title="Select post-code..." id="post-code" data-live-search-placeholder="Search desired post-codes here" data-live-search="true">
  </select>
</div>
```

My JSON from where the post-codes are being fetched -

```
  {
    "Country": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "name": "China",
      "capital": "Beijing",
      "divisions": ["01", "02", "03"],
      "districts": ["01", "02", "03"]
    },
    ........
   ],
  "Divisions": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "name": "Shengdong",
      "districts": ["01","20"]
    },
    ........
   ],
   "Subdistricts": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "name": "Dailang",
      "postcodes": ["736200","404000","100000"]
    },
    ........
   ]
 }
```

Every search box considers options as strings and search them based on data-tokens.

For live test - http://ni8mr.github.io/gpsl-ui/. You can check it by clicking **add new depot button**. You have to follow the selection hierarchy for getting post-codes selection options. At first country, than divisions, districts ...... post-codes.

May be it is an issue related to the plug-in i am using. **My question is, how can i overcome this barrier externally?** Ar first my idea was to, check if the "4730" can be made lowercased and hence search-able. But it has failed. My JS code for populating post-codes selection is like this -

```
$("#post-code").empty().append('<option data-tokens="' + related_postcodes +'" value="' + some_number + '">' + related_postcodes + '</option>').change(function(){
            ....some codes .....

      }).selectpicker('refresh');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in bootstrap-select. If you assign a data token that is a numeric value, the select isn't type-checking and converting it to a string. If you add another string value to the data-token, then the entire property is automatically casted to a string. If you do just want to have numbers for your zip code, you can add a trailing space to your code in the data-tokens property which will auto cast it for you (as long as that won't mess up any of your logic).

Example with trailing space:

```
$("#post-code").empty().append('<option data-tokens="' + related_postcodes +' " value="' + some_number + '">' + related_postcodes + '</option>').change(function(){
            ....some codes .....

      }).selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. What do you means by trailing space in data-tokens property ? Should i generate some random strings for data-tokens instead of numbers ? I can do that but that will need a lot of work.

Comment: If you render data-tokens like this: data-tokens="' + related_postcodes + ' " it should work for you. Notice I put a space between the single and double ending quotes.

Comment: So data-tokens should be blank ?

Comment: I have tried it, it doesn't work. Plus, i have to provide users with some related data-tokens so that they can search easily.

Comment: Add in a significant character to see if the whitespace is getting trimmed somewhere in your setup. Try doing related_postcodes + ' a' and see if it's searchable then.

Comment: Sholota ... wow man it has worked as you have suggested. Can you explain what is happening here ? It would help me to understand the process and i can use this technique next time in similar cases. :)   My guess is adding a character with related_postcodes make it recognizable as string ?

Comment: And please try to add the solution you have given me in the comment into the answer with explanation. :)

Comment: JS infers type. In this case, whatever the select is doing is treating numeric tokens as numbers. I would have thought that it would be treating them as strings, but alas it's not. The author would have to give you the "why" behind that. But if a number is combined with a non-numeric character, JS will automatically infer its type as a string. I don't know why this particular component only works with strings, again, a question for the author. But since it does, just make sure you give it strings to search by.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in bootstrap select so for that add this small fix in your `bootrap-select.js`

Replace this line of code

```
// var haystack = ($obj.data('tokens') || $obj.text()).toUpperCase();
```

By this line

```
var haystack = ($obj.data('tokens') || $obj.text()).toString().toUpperCase();
```

This will convert your *numeric value to String*.